VSCode autosuggest python imports without relying on Intellisense
This is explicitly about not using pylance/intellisense because it is broken sometimes, and would be easier to fix through text matching by identifying common names with hardcoded import statements.
I am using objects like AutoModel from the transformers and frequently come across objects that the auto-import suggestions cannot find.
Rather than bothering with finding the reason it doesn't find, I always want VSCode to suggest to do "from transformers import AutoModel" whenever it sees an undefined "AutoModel", so no need to scan through any python import directories.
Is this possible out-of-the-box or with some extension?
By the way, I already tried to add this to no avail (after reloading the window):
"python.analysis.packageIndexDepths": [
        {"name": "transformers", "index": 4,},
    ]



python.analysis.packageIndexDepths

This setting has been deprecated, you could try to add "python.analysis.extraPaths": "path/to/your/module" to your settings.json to make it work.

I am looking for a solution without Intellisense (which sometimes does not work), so only through text matching
